# Browsing Android File System

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file

i'm currently exploring android file / directories operations and i'm wondering how can i browse internal and external storage the same way a windows explorer could do ?

actually i'm reading [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and at this time i have no access to the hole storage hierarchy not only for my application, what i'm expecting is to be able to read files and directories names/contents, choose a path and so on...

what components should i use and if possible what free API can help me do this in the future ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a File Explorer you could use a component like [AndroidFileExplorer](https://github.com/dibakarece/AndroidFileExplorer) otherwise you have to build it from scratch. Remember also that some paths are not accessible without root permission.

Comment: I'just took a look at the link you provided , t's an app but i can get interesting things from source code, i'm beginner in both android and java and i want to stand on the basics, but what android API to use (apart from File object) in addition to java io if i happen to build this from scratch ?

Comment: There are many functions you have to use to build a file explorer, it you have little experience it would be better to look (or use) a component like the one I pointed. If you prefer to create it you could start from the File.listFiles() function in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html and put the items in a ListView - for example: `File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() ); File files[] = path.listFiles();`

Comment: You could also look this post: http://www.christophbrill.de/en_US/how-to-create-a-android-file-browser-in-15-minutes/ - it could give you a start

Comment: Thank you for your hints, i'm doing some testing to get the hole thing and to understand the basics, i plan to code some utility abstract class that will contain all methods that i would be using in the future, creating folders/files, deleting, and so on because it will be a good training for me.